# Inject service of parent module in NestJS

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, circular-dependency

I have three Modules in NestJS: `EndpointModule`, `JWTModule` and the specific Endpoints as Modules (for Example `InfoModule`)

My EndpointModule looks like this:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        JWTModule.withRSAKeys(
            Path.resolveByApp('./private.key'),
            Path.resolveByApp('./public.key')
        ),
        InfoModule,
        //More Endpoints
    ],
    exports: [JWTModule]
})
export class EndpointModule {}
```

JWTModule like this:

```js
@Module({
    providers: [JWTService],
    exports: [JWTService]
})
export class JWTModule {
    static async withRSAKeys(
        privateKeyPath: string,
        publicKeyPath: string
    ): Promise<DynamicModule> {
        return {
            module: JWTModule,
            providers: await this.createProviders(privateKeyPath, publicKeyPath)
        };
    }
```

As you can see `JWTModule` is a dynamic module. Now i want to inject the exported `JWTService` in my endpoint controllers. For Example:

```js
@Module({
    controllers: [InfoController]
})
export class InfoModule {}

@Controller()
export class InfoController {
    constructor(private jwt: JWTService){};
```

This does not work. I have to import the `EndpointModule` in my `InfoModule` but this creates a circular dependency. Are there any ways to avoid this? Should i reorder my Modules?

Comment: Did you add JWTModule as an import for InfoModule?

Comment: I can not do that because JWTModule is dynamic and expects arguments (like in EndpointModule) @ChukwumaEzumezu please see my comment in Maciej's answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `JWTModule` in `InfoModule` or decorate `EndpointModule` with `Global()`

Comment: I also thought of that. But if i do that in InfoModule: `@Module({ imports: [ JWTModule ] })` i get errors. It is an dynamic module and needs some arguments (like in EndpointModule). Can i tell my InfoModule to use the existing JWTModule?

Comment: Only by making EndpointModule global. Nest.js flow works that the lower module doesn't know the upper's imports or provide unless the upper module is global.

But maybe something like that will work:
#InfoModule
providers: [{provide: JWTService, useExisting: JWTService}]

but I don't know if it will work and even so, this is a workaround

Comment: Man you just saved my day. Thank you!